# edit website "number" in the IIS Metabase

Tags: iis, metabase

If you open the IISMetabase xml file you will see something like

```
<IIsWebServer   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1739153350"
        AuthFlags="0"
        ServerAutoStart="TRUE"
        ServerBindings=":80:"
        ServerComment="myWebSite"
    >
</IIsWebServer>
```

The 1739153350 in the above snippet was automagically generated. Can I hard-code it? If so how do I do it?

TIA
rams

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Metabase Explorer from IIS Resource Toolkit and change the "key". Be sure to backup your metabase.xml

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the website, and "Save As"
2. Save it to a .txt file on your desktop
3. Open the txt file, and replace **"/1739153350"** with **"/{newid}"** (be sure to include the beginning slash). Save.
4. Right click on websites, "Create New From File", point it to the file you just edited.
5. The website will be added in the "Stopped" state (because of a duplicate host header). Stop the old site and start the new one.

This is all from memory because I have done this about one gajillion times.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 2 steps first

1. In IIS Manager, right-click the local computer, and then click Properties.
2. Select the Enable Direct Metabase Edit check box.

Next directly open the metabase.xml file and change the value and save it in the same location, But take backup of metabase.xml before doing this, If any thing goes wrong we can restore the file or restore the recent xml file which is automatically saved in history folder. Path of history directory is %systemroot%System32\Inetsrv\History.